# C++ pass string by reference vs pass char array by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stdstring

Okay so I'm new to C++ and I just wanted to ask why you shouldn't pass the char array by reference with the "&" sign but you should with strings since both arguments are pointers. Example code I have written:

```
void changeChar(char* buffer, int bSize) {
    strcpy_s(buffer, bSize, "test123");
}

void changeString(string* buffer) {
    *buffer = "test321";
}

char mychar[10] = "hello world";
string mystr;

changeChar(mychar, sizeof(mychar));
changeString(&mystr);
```

Comment: Please note that there are no references being used in the example you provided.

Comment: `std::string` is not a pointer, it is a *class*. Passing a class by value creates a copy, while passing it by reference allows you to access the original object. Passing a pointer by reference has no net gain over passing it by value, while in case of `std::string`, it avoids the creation of a copy.

Comment: `char mychar[10] = "hello world";` What do you think is doing?

Comment: Okay, but am I not assigning the pointer "buffer" the memory adress of mystr or what is going on?

Comment: The `&` in `changeString(&mystr);` is the address-of operator (nothing to do with references) and it returns the address of `mystr` see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator

Comment: @RichardCritten yes I know, so am I right when I say that the string pointer "buffer" contains the memory adress of mystr and therefor "buffer" points directly to mystr without any weird copies being made?

Comment: @Bob__ I think it allocates 10 bytes of ram memory and then stores the array containing all the chars in the string you provided there.

Comment: Almost. The string literal `"hello world"` needs 12 chars (don't forget the null-terminator). You cold use `char mychar[] = "hello world";`.

Comment: @JohnnyCode 1 question per post please and don't try to change the question in the comments.  The title now does not match what you are asking.  Suggest you post a new question.

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm sorry but I still don't understand why I need to use the "&" sign when passing the string as parameter but not while passing the char. So I guess I don't want to move away from that question.

Comment: `void changeString(string& buffer) { buffer="test321"; }` when you pass the array the array is already an address i.e. pointer

Comment: @AndersK. thank you, I think I understand but why did you post the changeString code when talking about arrays?

Comment: @JohnnyCode u never give the address of a std::string, you either pass it by reference or by value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`changeChar()` takes a `char*` pointer to a `char` located *somewhere* in memory (the function assumes the `char*` is actually pointing to the 1st `char` of a `char[]` array of the specified size).

Any fixed-length array **decays** into a pointer to its 1st element when referred to by just its name. So there is no need to (nor can you) use `operator&` to pass your `mychar[]` array to your `changeChar()` function when it takes a `char*` pointer.

If you don't want to pass `mychar` by pointer, you have to pass it by reference instead (otherwise, passing it by value will make a copy of the array, and then the function won't be able to modify the original array).  In which case, you must include the array's size as part of the data type used for the reference, eg:

```
void changeChar(char (&buffer)[12]) {
    strcpy_s(buffer, 12, "test123");
}

char mychar[] = "hello world";
changeChar(mychar);
```

However, this works only if all arrays passed to the function have the same size. If you need to pass arrays of different sizes, make the function be a template instead so the compiler can deduce the size of the array being passed in, eg:

```
template<size_t size>
void changeChar(char (&buffer)[size]) {
    strcpy_s(buffer, size, "test123");
}

char mychar[] = "hello world";
changeChar(mychar);
```

---

`changeString()` takes a `string*` pointer to a `string` object located *somewhere* in memory.

You can't pass an object by pointer without using `operator&` (or `std::addressof()` when a class overrides `operator&`) to get the address of the object (unless it was allocated with `new`, which is not the case in your example).

If you don't want to pass the `string` object by pointer, you have to pass it by reference instead (otherwise, passing the object by value will make a copy of the object, and the function won't be able to modify the original object):

```
void changeString(string &buffer) {
    buffer = "test321";
}

string mystr;
changeString(mystr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much I think I understand! So arrays in general kind of becomes a pointer when referenced by name or is it only char arrays or am I totally wrong?

Comment: Any kind of fixed-length array will decay into a pointer, it is not specific to just `char` arrays.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. This helped me understand alot more.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Declaration of function look like this 
`void changeChar(char (&)[size]); ` right ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane if you are trying to forward-declare the function, then yes, if`size` is a constant. Otherwise, no, it would be `template <size_t size> void changeChar(char (&)[size]);` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know, that `std::string` is not a built-in type. It is a class, that implements all kind of custom behaviour, such as creating hard copy on object copying.

```
"some text" // this is a string literal, meaning the type is const char[num]
```

When you enter a string literal, it is located most likely inside section of the code named ".rodata" (read only data). You cannot legaly modify value of this characters. The text has also a "null terminator" - character of value of zero at the end. It is useful, because you need to know when the literal ends. `num` is always `number of characters` `+1`, because of the null terminator.

When you write this:

```
const char* text = "hello world!";
// note that this is illegal:
// char* text = "hello world!"; // literal is read-only.
```

You just say:

> let `text` point to the memory, where the literal is located.

Copying text actually requires from as more work. It must be done explicitly:

```
char* notReadOnly = new char[30]; // you can allocate some more
// program will still interpret character of value 0 as the end, even if buffer is bigger
std::strcpy(notReadOnly, "hello world");
// use string literal as src in std::strcpy
```

Note, that you need to manually delete it too:

```
delete[] notReadOnly;
```

`std::string` makes it a lot easier. It automatically copies the text, when you write sth like this:

```
std::string text = "some string literal";
```

`std::string`'s copy constructor also makes hard copy of the buffer. Even if `std::string` class looked like this:

```
class string
{
    char *buffer;
    std::size_t numberOfCharacters;
};
```

Every time its copied, it performs hard copy of the `buffer`, which can look like this:

```
class string
{
    // rest
    string(const string &other)
    {
        numberOfCharacters = other.numberOfCharacters;
        buffer = new char[numberOfCharacters];
        // copy everything
        std::strncpy(buffer, other.buffer, numberOfCharacters);
    }
};
```

Note, that this is just a simplified example.

```
std::string a = "some text";
std::string b = a; // copy constructor is called. It uses method implemented above

const char* x = "some text2";
const char* y = x; // copy constructor is called. Only the address is copied, there is no hard copy of the actual buffer.
```

Copy constructors are also called, when you pass variable to a function as parameter. Compilers can optimize it however in some common cases.

Comment: sorry I'm new so I don't quite understand... do my code make any extra copies of "mystr" or does the string pointer "buffer" point directly to "mystr"?

Comment: When you copy pointers to char, you copy *only* the memory address. Both pointers point to the same location.